# References to align with the rest of the text

Tags: bibliographies, horizontal-alignment

I'm using LaTeX2e and don't want the abbreviations that appear in my text (at `\cite`) to appear also in the left margin of the bibliography, so have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%...
\makeatletter
%...
\def\@biblabel#1{}
%...
\makeatother
%...
\begin{document}
%...
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Aitken 1935]{Aitken}Aitken AC (1935): Note on selection from a multivariate normal population. \emph{Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society}, 4:106--110.
%...
\end{thebibliography}
%...
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the bibliography items are indented slightly more than the rest of the article text:

[image]

I want them indented the same as the article text. How do I get the references over to the left?

(Note: I don't want to use BibTeX, as (a) using it for this is overkill (especially since I don't plan to use these references in future papers) and (b) it's another thing I'd have to learn.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can redefine the `thebibliography` environment, as defined in `article.cls`, to suppress the additional space; in the following example I show the redefinition (it consists in commenting out the line `\advance\leftmargin\labelsep`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            %\advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Aitken 1935]{Aitken}Aitken AC (1935): Note on selection from a multivariate normal population. \emph{Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society}, 4:106--110.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Using the `etoolbox` package, this redefinition can be done in a shorter way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{}
\makeatother
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\advance\leftmargin\labelsep}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Aitken 1935]{Aitken}Aitken AC (1935): Note on selection from a multivariate normal population. \emph{Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society}, 4:106--110.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Come to think of it, if I'm redefining `thebibliography`, then why not use `\list{}` instead of `\list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}` and then not need to redefine `biblabel`? (I haven't tried it, but it seems like it should work.)